# Which Static Route to Add in Windows to access resources on VPN

Tags: vpn, static-routes

I have a VPN Connection, Initially when i was connecting to VPN my internet connectivity was lost. Then i read about disabling the "use default gateway on remote network" check. When i unchecked that it i got internet connectivity however i cannot access resources over VPN.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMbkc.png)

I have read online, about adding a static route, but the issue i don't know what static route we need to add?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please specify what do you mean by accessing resource over VPN? What you are looking for I think is [split tunneling](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//bb878117(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN). You can add a separate static route for your VPN only beside your default gateway.